# How to get "Required reviewers" using RestAPI from specific branch on Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-policy, azure-rest-api

Getting the branch policy from Azure DevOps Services return only the policy type but not the "Required reviewers" - **looking for Reviewer Name or Team Name .**
I could not find a call to extract the "Required reviewers" from the selected policy/branch.

looked for policy extraction method could not find .

Answer (score 0):

For REST API checkout the Policy Configurations. The Confguration object in the example on the page shows a `settings.requiredReviewerIds` property with what seems to be an array of Azure AD *Object IDs* for the required reviewers.

As an alternative to REST, *az cli* also has the `az repos policy required reviewer` command documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/policy/required-reviewer?view=azure-cli-latest) to manage reviewers in branch policies.

Comment: could not find a way get from requiredId the actual details of the user/group